# What is the "real" memory of my graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, specifications, directx

I purchased a desktop two years back asking the vendor to install an Nvidia 9400 GT 1GB graphics card. The NVIDIA website provides the following technical specifications:

Memory Specs -> Standard Memory Config = 512MB

The DirectX diagnostics (dxdiag) give the following details:

```
       Card name: NVIDIA GeForce 9400 GT
    Manufacturer: NVIDIA
       Chip type: GeForce 9400 GT
        DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
      Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0641&SUBSYS_40091682&REV_A1
  Display Memory: 1775 MB
Dedicated Memory: 1009 MB
   Shared Memory: 765 MB
```

I'm confused about what the "real" memory is. Is it 1GB? 512MB? Does the words "Integrated RAMDAC" mean the display shares memory with the RAM and the total is 1GB?

Comment: It looks like it is a 1GB card.  How much memory does your system have?

Comment: Integrated RAMDAC= Random Access Memory Digital-to-Analog Converter. It's a piece of hardware which produces analog signal which drives analog monitors. Integrated in this case should not be a problem. Integrated RAMDACs have been the norm for quite a while.

Comment: Thanks AndrejaKo. Ramhound, my system has a 2GB RAM, excluding the Graphics Card - which I was hoping will be 1GB additional when used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

download this Tool [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) and run it. It will read all the data of your GPU and show you your memory.

[image]

Comment: Confirmed that memory size is 1024MB. Not sure why the NVIDIA website says otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it :
Dedicated Memory: 1009 MB - this is the onboard memory on the video card itself 
Shared Memory: 765 MB - This is system memory (plugged into motherboard) the card can use along with its own dedicated onboard ram.

Answer (score 0):

Another neat application to check this information, and additional information about your PC, is Speccy https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy.

Pretty neat information, not invasive/instrusive and no adware software either (Just make sure you're getting it from an official site).

Hope this helps.